# Creating multiple dynamic drop down in Excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I am fairly new to Excel and I would like to create multiple dynamic drop down list that are dependent on the previous Column. I have looked online and I have only come across solutions that include 2 columns but not more than 2 and I would need some assistance on how will I be able to create multiple dynamic drop down list.

As  seen from the image, there are 3 columns: Component_1, Component_2, Component_3

**What I am trying to achieve is that in the first drop down.**

**It will have the unique values in Component_1 (Empty, A, B, C)**

**In the second drop down Component_2 it will depend on the previous column which is Component_1.**

If the value in Component_1 is selected as A Component_2 will have (AA, AB)

If the value in Component_1 is selected as B Component_2 will have (BB)

If the value in Component_1 is selected as C Component_2 will have (CC, CD)

**In the third drop down Component_3 it will depend on the previous column which is Component_2.**

If the value in Component_1 is selected as A and Component_2 is selected as AA Component_3 will have (AAA)

If the value in Component_1 is selected as A and Component_2 is selected as AB Component_3 will have (ABB, ABC)

If the value in Component_1 is selected as B and Component_2 is selected as BB Component_3 will have (BBB)

If the value in Component_1 is selected as C and Component_2 is selected as CC Component_3 will have (CCC)

If the value in Component_1 is selected as C and Component_2 is selected as CD Component_3 will have (CCD, CCE)

[image: Screenshot of the data]

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a helpful walkthrough on Ablebits.com](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/09/30/dependent-cascading-dropdown-lists-excel/), which I recommend.

The easiest way I know to manage this is to put your data into tables with the headers being the drop-down selection from the prior menu.

In your example the first menu is just "A","B","C" & " ", so Table 1 should have all the drop down options you want listed under those headers.

Open data validation and set your first validation to pull from your first list "A","B","C" & " ". Go to your next cell, open data validation and set it to list, type in this formula:

`=INDIRECT("Table1["&A1"]")`

This assumes that your first drop down is in A1 and the table is named "Table1", so change as appropriate.

Then in the cell where you want your third drop down repeat what you did for cell 2, except the formula would be updated to:

`=INDIRECT("Table2["&B1&"]")`

Assuming that your second drop down is in B2 and your second table is named "Table2".

Good luck, I hope this helps!